# scrollIntoView when Angular Router change

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router

I am trying to use scrollIntoView when my page is loaded and when a user clicks on one of the menu buttons.
Therefore, I am subscribing to the route params in ngOnInit (Also tried in ngAfterViewInit) and inside there I activate "scrollIntoView()".
The issue is that it is not working on the First loading of the page (if the client enter direcly to www.website.co.il/home/componentName instead of www.website.co.il/home) but only if I change my route after the page is loaded.

app-routing.module.ts

```
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent },
{ path: 'home/:section', component: HomeComponent },
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }
```

navbar.component.html

```
        <li
            class="menuItem"
            *ngFor="let menuItem of (menuItems$ | async).menuItems; trackBy: trackByFunction">
            <a
                class="menuItem__link"
                [routerLink]="['home', menuItem.link]">{{ menuItem.name }}</a>
        </li>
```

our-services.component.ts

```
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    if(params.section === COMP_LINK_NAME) {
      this.container.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "center", inline: "center" });
    }
  });
}
```

COMP_LINK_NAME is const parameter of our-services component

Comment: what is the console.log(this.container) say ?

Comment: @noririco - Already checked it. An element ref (as expected) is received.

Comment: try to wrap with : `setTimeout(function() { 
  this.container.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "center", inline: "center" });
}, 2000);` if its ok try to tweak 2000 to smaller value

Comment: Following up on noririco's comment, do you have things loading that are not in the resolver, inside your component. Most likely the container is not yet rendered fully or  positioned on the view yet properly. If noririco's comment works, then it's an indication that your view is not ready.